# How do I add a Bottom navigation view outside of the grid layout

Tags: bottomnavigationview

When I try to add a bottom navigation view it is being placed at the top instead of the bottom. I tried adding a frame layout with bottom constraints but still didn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    tools:context=".ListItemsActivity">

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:columnCount="2"
        app:rowCount="2"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="2dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="2dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/RadioButtonText"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/CheckBoxText"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/SwitchText"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill" />

    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottm_nav_menu"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my code right now, but the bottom navigation view is appearing on the top in front of my buttons